# How to separate functionality of Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this extend text component which can add auto complete, tagging, and search query capabilities to a input/textarea (which can work independently or together).  Instead of having all the functionality included in one big directive, I would like to move the auto complete, tagging, and search query functionality into there own directives in order to make changing or replacing them easier.  Any type of communication that needs to happen between them I imagine would be done through the directive controller's.

The a small prototype on how I plan on doing this is here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/836sPtrBt4XXOeDI8mLf?p=preview

Where the element must have the `extend-text` attribute but then can also optional have any of the `et-auto-complete`, `et-tagging`, or `et-search-query`.

Is this the angular way of separating this type of functionality for directives?